# Approximating $\int_0^x\operatorname{cos(t)}e^{-t^2 / 10} \mathrm{dt}$

Tags: definite-integrals, approximation

> Approximate values of the integral $$I(x)=\int_0^x\cos(t)e^{-t^2 / 10} \mathrm{d}t$$ are given in the following table:
>
> \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
> x& \pi/2 & \pi & 3\pi/2 & 2\pi \\ \hline
>  I(x)&0.95 &0.44 &0.18&0.22\\ \hline
> \end{array}
> then the best approximation of $I(5\pi/4)$ is?

This is a very strange question that I encountered. I tried splitting the bounds of the integral into various intervals but in vain.

Any hint in the right direction is appreciated!

P.S: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2104244/734160) post is the same but I wish to seek a simpler answer.

Source: Test of mathematics at the 10+2 level

Comment: What are you currently studying? Because there are a lot of ways to approximate this integral, from really simple to much more complex. There is no “best” approximation, other than the actual number itself. It seems possibly you are intended to use only the table given, rather than any knowledge of estimating integrals.

Comment: how about splitting into two integrals $\int_0^\pi$ and $\int_\pi^{\pi+\pi/4}$ and applying mean value theorem for the second one?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think thats important. Though Im not from the states, I would say I know pretty much everything till calc-2

Comment: @rrv I do not actually know the mean value theorem. Ill take a look at it and inform you

Comment: You could do a polynomial interpolation.

Comment: The [10+2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10%2B2) level is the last two years of school in secondary school (sixth form), equivalent to the Indian +2.